# Can not name my function CreateWindow

Tags: c++, winapi

I can not create my own function called CreateWindow because there's already one defined in the win32 header. It's just that I can't even do that in my own namespace either.
What's the issue really?

```
MyNamespace::MyOwnWindowClass * Bit::CreateWindow( )
{
// Code here.
}
```

Getting errors such as:

```
Error   5   error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
Error   2   error C2039: 'CreateWindowExW' : is not a member of 'MyNamespace'
```

Comment: There is a #define for CreateWindow, I guess you will have problems using it as a function name because of that. Maybe you can #undef it or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that MS used a #define (I believe to map the function based on whether you are building for narrow or wide string). You have three choices. First, don't use CreateWindow in a file that must include the relevant MS header. Or, you could #undef it (I wouldn't recommend this) before using your function. Finally, you could just rename yours.

Comment: It seems like I could #undef it in the .cpp where I defined the function. It's compiling and working without any issues. I guess it's alright as long I'm not supposed to call that Win32 function in that particular .cpp file?

Comment: I think you'll be OK with it. When I run into this problem I prefer the first option--separating concerns wherever possible and using separate cpp's. Sometimes though when you are dealing with someone else's #define, you can be backed into a corner where there's no reasonable way to avoid #undef. It's a good lesson in why not to #define things this way in the first place.

Comment: Yeah since I'm not called the Win32 function called CreateWindow in that .cpp where I #undef:ed it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: A 4th solution is to _always_ include the Windows header first. That way, your declaration will also expand to `CreateWindowW`, and it's sufficient to be consistent.